# In Office 365 - Excel 2016, how do I protect the file to require a password to modify it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, microsoft-excel-2016, password-protection

I remember back in Excel 2010 it was possible to set a document as for the user to be open to read only and if you wanted to make changes, you had to input a password to do so.

We're using Excel 2016 as part of the Office365 solution now and i cant seem to find any setting that allows the users to open the document without a password to read only and not be able to do changes. Yet they should be able to input a password if they wanted to change something.

How do I protect the file to require a password to modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft;

> You can set two passwords on the file - one to open the file as
>   read-only, and the other to modify. Then you can share the appropriate
>   passwords with the users depending on the access level they should
>   have.

This applies To: Excel 2016 Excel 2013 Excel 2010 Excel 2007 Excel 2016 for Mac;

> 1. In the Excel file, click File > Save As.
> 2. Click a location, such as Computer or your My Site web page.
> 3. Click a folder, such as Documents or one of the folders on your
>      OneDrive, or click Browse.
> 4. In the Save As dialog box, go to the folder you want to use, then
>      click Tools and then click General Options.
> 5. You can specify one or both passwords here, one to open the file,
>      another to modify the file, depending on your requirements.
> 6. Click Save.

[source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Protect-an-Excel-file-7359d4ae-7213-4ac2-b058-f75e9311b599)

Comment: I've been looking for an hour and couldn't find it - you helped me a great deal. Thank you ;)